# How often do db specific error codes change

Tags: java, mysql, database, oracle, postgresql

I need to throw specific exceptions when the database returns unique key violation exception. For this I'm using getSQLState() and getErrorCode() to identify when unique key constraint is violated.

I would like to know if and how often the vendor specific error codes and SQL States are changed

If I use sqle.getErrorCode() and sqle.getSQLState() to identify the exception type how often will I need to change the code.

Databases I am testing on are Postgres, Oracle and MySQL. Code looks somewhat like this

```
catch (SQLException sqle) {
        if(sqle.getSQLState().equals(someSQLState) && sqle.getErrorCode() == someErrorCode) {
            throw new SomeException(SomeParameters);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You would have to ask the individual vendors, but the only sane answer is surely 'never'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Oracle** - The error codes never change.  There's no written guarantee of this, but the error codes are [thoroughly documented](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ERRMG/toc.htm).  I've never seen one change and surely Oracle knows that changing error codes would be disastrous.

**PostgreSQL** - The above answer (for Oracle) applies also to PostgreSQL. The following statement can be found in [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/errcodes-appendix.html):

> Applications that need to know which error condition has occurred
>   should usually test the error code, rather than looking at the textual
>   error message. The error codes are less likely to change across
>   PostgreSQL releases, and also are not subject to change due to
>   localization of error messages.

**MySQL** - ?